# Complexity of Spatial Branch and Bound

Tags: optimization, time-complexity, mixed-integer-programming, branch-and-bound

What is the time complexity of Spatial Branch and Bound?
I'm interested in how does the complexity depends on the number of variables and their dimensions.

Thank you!

Comment: The [link](https://optimization.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/Spatial_branch_and_bound_method) has references in the bottom of the page to materials, describing the algorithm. You can try to find these materials and look for complexity there.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link you shared only says that it is NP-hard but harder. I still don't understand what it means "harder" in terms of complexity. Is the worst-case complexity the same as for other branch and bound methods? Is it exponential in the worst-case?

Comment: in the bottom of the link I gave there is a section called References. I mean that if you'll find documents referenced there, you'll be able to get more information on the algorithm. Alas, the link I provided does not have what you want alone.